# Escaping double quotes in bash not working as expected

Tags: bash

This example works well:

```
if [[ "$(mysql -sse 'USE my_bd; SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table" -gt "0" ]]; 
  then echo 1;
  else echo 0;
fi
```

But I need to add a WHERE clause that needs quotes `'` inside   `mysql -e 'query...'`

So I need to change the quotes order like this and enclose the `mysql -e "query..."` with double quotes

I have tried to escape with `\"`

```
if [[ "$(mysql -sse \"USE my_bd; SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table WHERE my_column = 'something'\"" -gt "0" ]]; 
  then echo 1;
  else echo 0;
fi
```

But that has thrown a bash error

> -bash: command substitution: line 21: syntax error near unexpected token `('

I saw other questions about `How to escape double quotes in bash?` but the answers don't work in my case

Comment: I don't see the `$(mysql` getting closed

Comment: You have reason if I change `"$(mysql` to `$(mysql` working good. Bfff I have tried a lot of combinations but not that one. Thank's The bellow answer also work. I need more coffee :)

Comment: Since the values on both sides is a number, it works without `" "`, but if the value is expected to be a string, it won't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly use the below command:

```
if [[ "$(mysql -sse "USE my_bd; SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table WHERE my_column = 'something')" -gt "0" ]]; 
  then echo 1;
  else echo 0;
fi
```

I have just tested the above command in a test environment and it worked fine.  See the below similar example:

```
 if [[ "$(mysql -sse "use testdb ; SELECT COUNT(*) from student where stu_id = '1001'")" -gt 0 ]];
   then echo "1" ; 
   else echo "0"; 
 fi
 1
```

Comment: You have also reason. I'm fill ridiculuos ;)

Comment: Please refer the **Command Substitution** section in `man bash`.  "When using the $(command) form, all characters between the parentheses make up the command; none are treated specially."

Comment: Thank's. Is good to know that. (I have no study on informatics ... but I try to learn as I can )